# При увеличивании размера сайта в браузере текст не увеличивается внутри контейнера а смещается вниз почему то

Tags: html

```
<div class="kontakt-container">
        <section class="section-bg" style="background-image: url(https://wallpaperbat.com/img/460248-i-love-football-wallpaper.png);">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="kontakt-add">
                        <div class="kontakt-name">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <h3 class="kontakt-name-text">КОНТАКТЫ</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="kontakt-list">
                            <div class="kontakt-tg">
                                <div class="row-tg">
                                    <a href="https://t.me/chat_turefootball" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-telegram"></i>    Канал в Телгерамме</a>
                                    <a href="https://t.me/turefootball" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-telegram"></i>    Чат в Телгерамме</a>
                                    <a href="https://t.me/Kumhk" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-telegram"></i>    Администратор</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="kontakt-donate">
                                <div class="kontakt-donate-text">
                                    <p>Если вы хотите выразить благодарность администраторам за их работу и усилия,<br> вы можете сделать это, переведя денежные средства на удобное для вас место &#128521;</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="kontakt-qiwi">
                                    <img src="https://fifacenter.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/logo-qiwi-koshelek-300x137.png" alt="" width="85" height="39">
                                    <div class="qiwi-tel"><p-2>+792</div></p-2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="kontakt-card">
                                    <img src="https://www.rostovregiongaz.ru/upload/images/payment/sber.png" alt="" width="137" height="70">
                                    <div class="card-nomer"><p-3>2202 2020 </p-3></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>        
    </div>[![при увеличенной размере вот][1]][1]
```

---

[image: это при увеличенном размере]

это при увеличенном размереэто при увеличенном размереэто при увеличенном размереэто при увеличенном размере

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос стили для элементов